# what is the point of `++a=20;`

Tags: c++

I got confused when accidentally tried this code `++a=20;`, which is not allowed in C. But it works and `a` turns out to be 20. Is it working with pointers?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int a=10;
   ++a=20;
   cout<<a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And that is from https://godbolt.org/

```
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 10
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 20
```

Comment: There is no point :)

Comment: Same as `a = 20;`.

Comment: (a) Your question asks about `a++=20;`, and your code shows `++a=20;`. These are different things. (b) There may be no point with ordinary non-volatile arithmetic types, but there could be differences with classes (where `++` is defined to do something more than a simple increment) or volatile types.

Comment: With plain assignment? No point. And unless we are assuming C++17, it's undefined anyway. But with C++17 and its sequencing guarantees, a compound assignment like  `++a %= 20` is a neat way to do an increment modulo 20.

Comment: "Is it working with pointers?" At the CPU level, yes. `rbp` is likely a pointer to the variables of `main`. You probably did not make an optimized build, so the compiler did not use the faster CPU registers to hold `a`. Or even more likely, an optimized build would just have done `cout << 19` and skip the whole calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Pointless

Let's read the Assembly code. 
`mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 10` 
4 byte (32 bit) is allocated for the integer variable a. Therefore it is positioned in [rbp-4]. This code simply assign its value to 10. Now a = 10.

`add DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1` 
It is equivalent to adding 1 to a 
This can be both `a++` or `++a`. However they are slightly different. Former returns the value of a, and then increments it. Latter increments the value of a, and then returns it.

`mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 20` 
It is equivalent to a = 20.

So the steps are like these actually: 
a = 10 
a++ 
a = 20

That's why a is equal to 20 at the end.

Comment: Also when switching on optimization ones sees even on the compiler explorer, that the compilers simply reduce the machine code to "lets print out 20"

Answer (score 1):

> tried this code a++=20;, which is not allowed in C. But it works and a turns out to be 20.

It is also not allowed in C++ and doesn't work. You'll notice that isn't what you used in the example program.

> what is the point of `++a=20;`

You're overwriting `a` immediately after incrementing the previous value. There is no point in writing that.

But more generally, there are other cases where using `++a` as an lvalue can have a point.

> Is it working with pointers?

You aren't using pointers in your example. But similar expression would work with pointers as well.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, there is a difference in pre-increment and post-increment [operators signature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec):

```
    T& T::operator++();     // pre-increment
    T T::operator++(int);   // post-increment
```

pre-increment operator returns a reference to the updated variable, so it can be further used as lvalue, e.g.:

```
    int a = 10;
    ++a += 20; // a = 31
```

but post-increment operator returns previuos (temporary) value, which will give compilation error if attempted to be used as lvalue:

```
    int a = 10;
    a++ += 20; // error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```